# C++11 std::chrono::duration_cast<> text of units being used

Tags: c++11, time, c++-chrono

I am writing a templated timer class where one of the template typenames is the resolution being used, for example `std::chrono::milliseconds`.

I would like to be able to output the result of the measurement with the proper units based on the resolution that was selected:

```
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<Resolution>(Clock::now() - mStart).count();
```

I would like to complete this statement with the units; is there a C++11 function that can give me the text of the "Resolution" being used, i.e. the string "milliseconds".

Answer (score 1):

http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration.io says that `std::cout << std::chrono::milliseconds(23)` should output "23ms"

@Acorn pointed out in a comment that this call was added for C++20.

You can roll it yourself:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds dur(23);
string s = tostring(dur.count()) + " milliseconds";
```

Comment: Isn't `operator<<` for `duration` only in C++20?

Comment: We all want to use C++20 so soon ;) By the way, I think OP wants to have it statically determined given a template argument, rather than hardcoded.

Comment: You can use date.h from https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date to get C++20 behavior today (in C++11/14/17).

Comment: @Acorn You are right; I would like it to be "statically determined given a template argument", in this case the template typename is Resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
template <class Duration>
struct DurationSuffix;

template <class Rep>
struct DurationSuffix<std::chrono::duration<Rep, std::ratio<1>>>
{
    static const char suffix[];
};

template <class Rep>
struct DurationSuffix<std::chrono::duration<Rep, std::milli>>
{
    static const char suffix[];
};

template <class Rep>
const char DurationSuffix<std::chrono::duration<Rep, std::ratio<1>>>::suffix[] = "s";

template <class Rep>
const char DurationSuffix<std::chrono::duration<Rep, std::milli>>::suffix[] = "ms";
```

And then you use it in your class like:

```
template <class Duration>
struct C
{
    static void f()
    {
        std::cout << DurationSuffix<Duration>::suffix << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<std::chrono::seconds>::f();
    C<std::chrono::milliseconds>::f();
    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
s
ms
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for something from std::chrono instead of writing myself

Comment: There is no functionality in C++11's `std::chrono`, so you will have to get it from somewhere else, be it a dependency or your own code.